# 'I'm happy/sorry/grateful that..." (thanks for.../happy to hear that...)

Tags: grammar, words

I'm new here so if a similar question have been asked before then feel free to delete the thread. 
I need some help with this "seemingly" easy phrasing. What kind of grammar pattern goes before words like よかった、ありがとう、うれしい、or any other adjective. 
is it TE form, plain form, plain form +　から And if I want to say "I was happy that he did it" Do I change うれしい and the verb or just うれしい？

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use the te-form in most situations:

- ～てくれ**て**ありがとう -- Thank you for ...ing
- ～**て**よかった -- It's good that... / I'm happy (to hear) that...
- ～と聞い**て**うれしい -- I'm happy to hear that...

Examples:

> 「手伝ってくれ**て**ありがとうございます。」
>   (Thank you for helping me.)
>   「お会いでき**て**よかったです。」
>   (I'm happy that I could see you.)
>   「合格したと聞い**て**うれしいです。」
>   (I'm happy to hear that you passed the test.)
>   「山田さんが来られなく**て**残念です。」
>   (I'm sorry that Yamada-san can't make it.)

---

> if I want to say "I was happy that he did it" Do I change うれしい and the verb or just うれしい？

I think you could say 「～～てうれしかった」.

> 「誘ってくれてうれしかったです。」
>   (I was happy that you invited me.)
>   「お父さんが帰ってきてうれしかった。」
>   (I was happy that my dad came back.)

Comment: I had once read somewhere that the only adjective that can follow a て form verb is ほしい. I see here you placed よい and うれしい after a て form. Was this advice wrong?

Comment: @TrevorKafka The advice you read is wrong. I can only guess that it was referring to adding auxilliaries to the te-form. In that case it might by right; I don't know. No others spring to mind, but it really isn't important. In the sentences above the part after the  te-form is not an auxilliary. It is joining two independent clauses. For example in お会いできてよかったです,  the second clause, よかったです,  is an entirely independent, standalone clause that means "I'm glad" (the "I'm" is implied by context"). So there is no restriction on what it can be (within reason).